# Cookie is not being set in the frontend even if it is present in the network tab

Tags: go, web, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I'm using Go and mux for the backend and simple html for the frontend.
The code for setting a cookie in the response (not full):

```
import  "github.com/gorilla/sessions" // this is where sessions come from

var store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("secret"))
store.Options = &sessions.Options{
        MaxAge:   3600 * 24,
        HttpOnly: true,
        Path: "/",
        Secure: true,
    }
session, _ := store.Get(request, "uid")
session.Values["uid"] = token
err = session.Save(request, writer)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
    return
}
```

and this is how I fetch:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8000/user/register", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          credentials: 'include',
          body: JSON.stringify(user),
        })
```

Also I have cors enabled on the backend:

```
c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"http://127.0.0.1:3000"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
    })
```

The content of the set-cookie header:

```
Set-Cookie: uid=jwt_token; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 20 Jul 2021 08:42:37 GMT; Max-Age=86400; HttpOnly; Secure
```

The cookie is not being set, but in the network tab the 'set-cookie' header is present. If you need more details about my code, ask in the comments and I will post a link to a pastebin.

Edit: until I find a better solution, I'm setting the cookie from the frontend, now the backend is sending a json with the data. A bit hacky considering my "initial design" but it works for now.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the contents of the `Set-Cookie` header you see in the Network tab?

Comment: Also, please specify where `sessions` comes from. Include all the relevant info (imports, etc.) in your code snippet.

Comment: @jub0bs I added both details to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this has to do with the `SameSite` cookie attribute. Check if your response's header `Set-Cookie` field has an yellow triangle in the end, indicating that something went wrong (I'm using chrome dev tools). If it does, you should use the same `domain` to `POST` to the server. For example;

- Say that you access the front-end from the `http://127.0.0.1:3000`, and your server is listening to the port `8000` then the request to the server should like like;

```js
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/register", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          credentials: 'include',
          body: JSON.stringify(user),
        })
```

This is happenning because `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are treated as different hosts.
For more information about the `SameSite` attribute you could check the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite).

Comment: i was almost dying with this issue